# NSNumberFormatter Not Working with Positive Input strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I am using `NSNumberFormatter` to make `NSNumber` form `NSString`. The strings can be in format like `@"-0.19" @"+0.70" @"0.70" @"581.25"`

I am using the following code to make `NSNumber` from these above strings

```
-(double) doubleValueForStocks:(NSString *)str{
     NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
     [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
     NSNumber *num =  [formatter numberFromString:str ];
}
```

I works in most of the cases but when the input is like `@"+0.70"` it returns `nil`.

Can anybody will guide me what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try different number style.

Comment: Might sound silly, but does it happen on the device, simulator, or both?

Answer (score 1):

**setPositivePrefix** in previous answer will not work for number without plus sign, so you can try this:

```
[formatter setPositiveFormat:@"'+'#"];
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried like this check with this it may be help you

```
- (double )stringWithDouble:(NSString *)value {
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [value
                                     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@""];
    NSNumber *num=[numberFormatter numberFromString:stringWithoutSpaces];
    return [num doubleValue];
}
```

**output**

```
0.700000



double value=[self stringWithDouble:@"+0.70"];
    NSLog(@"%f",value);
```

Answer (score 0):

try set positivePrefix for NSNumberFormatter:

```
[formatter setPositivePrefix:@"+"];
```

full method:

```
- (double)doubleValueForStocks:(NSString *)str {

    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setPositivePrefix:@"+"];
    NSNumber *num = [formatter numberFromString:str];
    return [num doubleValue];
}
```